# how to avoid null values in sobject

Tags: apex, trigger, javascript

how to avoid null values in getting values from object.Below are the code it is printing as 'null' if the value is not there.how to avoid this..

```
 for(Invention_Disclosure_New__c inv : idfs)
    {   
    String pdfContent = '' ;

        pdfContent = pdfContent + '<P>' + inv.get('Inventive_Features__c') + '</P>';}
```

In the above if the field inventive feature is empty it is printing as 'null',instead of this it should be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a ternary operator in your code that would look something like this:

```
String value = inv.get('Inventive_Features__c') > 0 ? inv.get('Inventive_Features__c') : null;
string pdfContent = '<P>' + value + '</P>';
```

Comment: Won't that throw NullPointerException anyways?

Comment: I've seen it used a lot in schema methods where the value can be null. Presumably, he could also use a null handler if that were the case or replace `null` with `''` or string.isBlank(), string.isEmpty(), etc. YMMV on any of those. If necessary, he could even wrap it in a try-catch block if it throws an NPE. I've had to do that myself on occasion. It's a PITA that a boolean isn't always a boolean in SF!

Answer (score 1):

Generically speaking, you can check if it's null:

```
Object value = inv.get('Inventive_Features__c');
if(value != null) {
  pdfContent = pdfContent + '<P>' + value + '</P>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `String.isNotBlank()` method of String class.

you can apply If check like this:

`if(String.isNotBlank(inv.get('Inventive_Features__c'))){}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of your field type (text/integer/other ?) but you should give a try to this:

```
String pdfContent = '';
for(Invention_Disclosure_New__c inv : idfs) {   
    String invVal = String.valueOf(inv.get('Inventive_Features__c'));
    pdfContent += !String.isBlank(invVal) ? '<p>' + invVal + '</p>' : '';
}
```

This will complete your "pdfContent" variable only if the value isn't empty or null.
However, if your require to complete it with empty `<p>`'s, just change it as following:

```
String pdfContent = '';
for(Invention_Disclosure_New__c inv : idfs) {   
    String invVal = String.valueOf(inv.get('Inventive_Features__c'));
    pdfContent += '<p>';
    pdfContent += !String.isBlank(invVal) ? invVal : '';
    pdfContent += '</p>'
}
```

This should match your need.

Comment: data type is long text,getting error as- Compile Error: Condition expression must be of type Boolean

Comment: Can you give more details ? 
I can't help you on this kind of error message without your code.